# SQL Server : summarizing data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

| CustomerID | Income | Date | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | 01/01/2015 | A |
| 1 | 300 | 01/01/2016 | B |
| 2 | 500 | 01/01/2016 | A |
| 2 | 300 | 01/01/2015 | B |

I want to see the list of `CustomerID` grouped by total income per year in separate columns.

I tried this code:

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID,
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(DateofPurchase) = '2015' 
            THEN SUM(income) 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS '2015',
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(DateofPurchase) = '2016' 
            THEN SUM(income) 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS '2016',
    CASE 
        WHEN ProductID = 'A' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'If bought A'
FROM
    exam
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMERID, productID, YEAR(DateofPurchase)
```

Expected results:

```
CustomerID (UNIQUE), Total income 2015, Total income 2016, If bought prod. A(yes/no), if total income (2015+2016) is above 1K (yes/no)
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're expecting with the various flaws in your query, For example you're probably expecting a single row per customer? "If bought A"  is "Yes" for both customers - add the expected tablular results for your sample data.

Comment: Do you see the implicit assumption in both your sample data and your query? Add some rows for a year that is not 2015 or 2016 and then tell us what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c9dca3fd0717f10907ed9169de670b4)

```
-- 
SELECT 
   CustomerID,
   SUM(Case when Year(DateofPurchase)='2015' then income else 0 end) as '2015',
   SUM(Case when Year(DateofPurchase)='2016' then income else 0 end) as '2016',
   max(Case when ProductID='A' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as 'If bought A'
from exam
group by  CUSTOMERID
```

- You show group only on CUSTOMER_ID, because you want to see your results per CustomerId, ( and not per CustomerId, productID, year )
- The SUM() should be put outside the `CASE WHEN...END`, because when the value of this case when is 0 you also need (or can) add it to the sum.  This eliminates the need for putting Year in the GROUP BY.
- The MAX(), on 'If bought A', is just a simple trick which works because 'Yes' is larger than 'No'

Finally, the second part of your question: (" if total income (2015+2016) is above 1K (yes/no)"  I will leave this as an exercise to you, with the comment that studying the OVER-clause (see: [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) might help solving it.